# Storing fields description

Tags: php, symfony, entity

I'm facing quite a common problem, but I have not found really convincing solutions so far. I'm working with Symfony2, and I'm making entities, which have attributes. Those attributes are meant to be manipulated throughout the website - nothing surprising here.

Now in most of my views (tables, forms, and so on), it's important to describe those attributes, with at least a short sentence to explain what the attribute represents.

What is a good solution to store the description of these attributes? I can see several ways to do that. Three come out:

- Storing them in the database, with my entities (quite heavy)
- Storing them in the entity (can hardly be changed)
- Storing them in an XML-like file (not too heavy, well adapted to translations, harder to manipulate)

Which of those solutions is the most used? What would be your advice?

And - if possible - how to best implement it in Symfony (especially with the file solution)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another option would be to use the translation feature to store your attribute descriptions. by that they are already in place for translating. if you use [KnpTransBundle](http://knpbundles.com/docteurklein/TranslatorBundle) they can be interactively translated and changed.

i use something similar for form labels/inline help

```
{# untested example code#}
{% for field in form.fields %}

    <label>
        {{ ('form.' ~ form.id ~ '.' ~ field.id ~ '.label')|trans() }}
    </label>

    {{form_widget(field)}}

    <div class="help">
        {{ ('form.' ~ form.id ~ '.' ~ field.id ~ '.label')|trans() }}
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```